# Embedded Google Calendar doesn't work when not logged in

Tags: google-calendar-api

My organization's website has some embedded Google Calendars that have previously been working but as of today stopped rendering when not logged in. We're pretty sure it's not a permission issue, as all our embedded calendars have the "Make publicly visible" checkbox checked, and furthermore the error in console doesn't mention permissions. When trying to access a page with a calendar when not logged in (such as in another browser, or in incognito/private mode) we get the following error (`...` = a bunch of stuff removed to save space):

```
GET https://calendar.google.com/.../m=embed net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Beneath that is another error about `window._init` not being a function, but trying to access `window._init` even when the calendar works gives an undefined value, so it leads me to believe the 404 is the main problem.

Is this something anyone has experienced before? Is Google just doing maintenance on Calendar causing some functionality to be broken?

Comment: I'm having the same error occurring with a similar situation - embedded calendars are not showing up consistently in IE11 and mobile safari, also in web safari if I check 'prevent cross-site trafficking'. If I reload many times on mobile on IE11 sometimes the calendar shows up. The error that I get in safari is 'undefined is not a function (near '...window._init'), and the error in IE11 is 'object doesn't support property or method '_init'. I hope google fixes this quickly!

Answer (score 1):

I am also experiencing the same thing for a client.  When I test in Incognito Mode/Private Mode, I am getting intermittent success.  Hopefully, Google is aware of the problem and is fixing the issue.  I also sent feedback through the Google Help to raise awareness.  Let's all hope for a speedy repair.

Comment: You can definitely get this for a calendar that has been set to public.

Answer (score 1):

> My shared/embedded Google Calendar is not working

Did you try?

1. Follow the instructions on [Add a Google calendar to your website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en)
2. In Access permissions enable **Make available to public**
3. copy paste your **Embed code** `<iframe src...>` manually(inject) in html?

Elements > select body element > inject your `<iframe src...>`

4. same as above but in **incognito mode**

I tested these steps and I get no Errors in: Chrome, Edge, IE, Safari mobile.

Comment: And I followed the same steps and do see the same error.